Unity stucks on domain reload (MacOS)
I am using Unity 2022.3.51f1, the project is imported from windows PC. Each time I edit script or do anything that needs to reload domain, it stucks at the end of the reloading. I need to restart the unity each time I edit any script if it is even a single line. How to fix it? I am using Jetbrains Rider for edit. MacOS Sequoia 15.2.

you'd need to look in the log files as to why its sticking, ive not seen that, you can of course turn domain reload off but it has side effects

Where to check logs?

Well the log files theres an option off the console, but on a mac, specifically no idea, as I dont mac

@YakupErdemYılmaz Log file locations. Also, you can try to uncheck the Jobs->Burst->Enable compilation, as it is the common source for such problems. If it doesn't help, you need to find out what makes the Editor fail to reload the domain. Or just try a different Unity version.

This is just Unity, it's been couple of years I have had that issue. I first thought it was the computer, so I got a new one, then I thought maybe it's Windows, and I got a mac. As soon as a project gets a bit of assets (not huge, just a dozen of scripts and this starts) and Unity is just being Unity.

@Everts that sounds pretty biased ^^ tbh getting a new PC or OS because a software misbehaves doesn't really sound like a good approach ^^ I have worked on very large projects for industry partners and big clients and never had these issues .. Is Unity the best and fastest software? For sure not but it isn't as bad as people claim either

I did not purchase a new computer, I requested it from employer. It was in case my laptop was acting weird for veing a bit old. But I tried brand new PC and brand new Mac with various projects (small and large) and it always starts when things get a bit big

You can only prevent PlayMode domain reload, but you can't prevent domain reload if you edit script. (or use Assembly Definition for specify reload. it helps)
Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor -> Enter Play Mode Settings then change to Do Not Reload Domain or Scene or just Reload Scene Only.

Seems like a know issue:
RIDER-120469 Unity gets stuck on domain reload when in debug mode using Rider
Upvote it to get updates.
